# Motorola Photon - Easy Tether - Linux connecting them all

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, android

I recently got Ubuntu on my computer (more specifically Xubuntu and Kubuntu) and have been loving it except that it will not recognize my phone meaning when I plug it in, nothing happens. There are drivers offered, but only for Windows. Can anyone tell me how to get it recognized?

Comment: You might try (also) asking this at [android.se]. We've quite a few regulars there who are Linux users.